# DNN Dynamic Form - Google Captcha

Tags: dotnetnuke, captcha

I have a Dynamic Form implemented on my page. I need to use the Google Captcha instead of the default Dynamic Form captcha . How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PortalKeeper module on Codeplex (http://ariciepkp.codeplex.com). It could help you to dynamicaly replace the default captcha without programmation.